# Yii2 provides wrong cookies data

Tags: cookies, yii2

Executing:

```
var_dump(Yii::$app->request->cookies);
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

Provides different result:

In the first case:

```
object(yii\web\CookieCollection)[60]
  public 'readOnly' => boolean true
  private '_cookies' => 
    array (size=1)
      '_csrf' => 
        object(yii\web\Cookie)[63]
          public 'name' => string '_csrf' (length=5)
          public 'value' => string '9uu8OFwtuhsqVMs_NXp3JYavB-SoNnhz' (length=32)
          public 'domain' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'expire' => null
          public 'path' => string '/' (length=1)
          public 'secure' => boolean false
          public 'httpOnly' => boolean true
```

In the second:

```
array (size=10)
      '__utma' => string '123' (length=3)
      '__utmc' => string '123' (length=3)
      '__utmz' => string '123' (length=3)
      'id' => string '16532' (length=5)
      'name' => string 'xxx' (length=3)
      'pwd' => string '8804c3c7b0d0addbecfaa2755946d5b6' (length=32)
      'access_token' => string 'xxx' (length=3)
      '_csrf' => string 'efc99e00558359ef396179424ff81f59b4197ec00b8ac84341eb13cbf06b3674a:2:{i:0;s:5:"_csrf";i:1;s:32:"9uu8OFwtuhsqVMs_NXp3JYavB-SoNnhz";}' (length=130)
```

Why cookies data are different?

Answer (score 0):

cookies accessed though `Yii::$app->request->cookies` are subject to cookie validation which is turned on by default.

To not break compatibility with 3rd parties `$_COOKIE` remains untouched.

read more here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html#cookie-validation